# Meteor: Subscribed Colletion doesn't update automatically (Reactivity)

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor

I'm facing the problem that adding data to a subscribed Collection doesn't automatically refresh the shown elements of a collection. If I add a new element the element show's up for a second and then disappears! Refreshing the browser (F5) and the new element shows up.
I put the subscription into Meteor.autorun but things kept beeing the same.

lists.html (client):

```html
    <<template name="lists">
  <div class="lists col-md-12" {{!style="border:1px red solid"}}>
        <!-- Checklist Adder -->
            <form id="list-add-form" class="form-inline" role="form" action="action">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" id="list-name" placeholder="Neue Liste" required="required"/>
              </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-add">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                      Neue Liste
                  </button>
            </form>
        <!-- Checklist Ausgabe -->
            <ul>
              <br/>
                {{#each lists}}
                    <li style="position: relative;"  id="{{this._id}}" data-id="{{_id}}" class="clickOnList">
                        <!--<input type="button" class="deleteLists" id="{{this._id}}" value="-" style="z-index: 999;"/> -->
                        <span  id="{{this._id}}" data-id="{{_id}}" style="padding-left: 10px; vertical-align:middle;">{{this.name}}</span>
                        <form id="changerForm_{{_id}}" class="changeList-name-form" data-id="{{_id}}" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top:0;">
                            <input id="changerText_{{_id}}"  type="text" class="list_name" data-id="{{_id}}" value="{{this.name}}" />
                        </form>
                        {{#if ownerOfList this._id}}
                        <a data-toggle="modal" class="userForListModal" id="{{this.name}}" data-id="{{this._id}}" data-target="#userForListModal">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="{{this.name}}" style="color:black;"data-id="{{this._id}}"></span><span style="color:black;" id="{{this.name}}" data-id="{{this._id}}" style="font-size: small; vertical-align: super">{{memberCount this._id}}</span></a>

                        <div class="deleteLists" id="dLBtn_{{_id}}"  data-id="{{this._id}}" style="float: right; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; visibility: hidden;">
                            <span class="deleteLists glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" data-id="{{this._id}}"></span>
                        </div>
                        {{else}}
                        <a class="userForListModal">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:black;"></span><span style="color:black;" style="font-size: small; vertical-align: super">{{memberCount this._id}}</span></a>
                        {{/if}}
                        <!--        <button type="submit" class="deleteLists btn btn-default btn-xs" id="dLBtn_{{_id}}"  data-id="{{this._id}}" style="float: right;"  > -->
                        </button>
                    </li>

                {{/each}}
            </ul>
  </div>


<div class="modal fade" id="userForListModal" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="userForListModalLabel"></h4>
      </div></template>
      <div class="modal-body col-md-12">
        <div id="userForListModalUsers">

        </div>
        <p>Neuen Benutzer zur Checkliste hinzufügen:</p>
        <form id="list-addUser-form" class="form-inline" role="form" action="action">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              {{inputAutocomplete settings id="name-list-addUser" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Benutzer Name" required="required"}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="submit-list-addUser">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                  Benutzer hinzufügen
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div id="userForListModalerrorMessage" style="color:red; display: none; text-align:left"></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</template>
<template name="userPill">
    <span class="label" style="color:black">{{username}}</span>
```

lists.js (client):

```js
Template.lists.lists = function(){ return Lists.find(); }


Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");


Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('lists');
})
```

lists.js

```
    var activeListName = "";
var activeListID = "";

Template.lists.lists = function()
{
        return Lists.find();
}

Template.lists.memberCount = function(id)
{
     var count = "";
     Meteor.call("listMemberCount", id, function(error,result)
                  {
                    if (error) {
                         console.log("List not initialized:" + error.reason);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         Session.set("countMember_"+id,result);
                    }
                  });
     return Session.get("countMember_"+id);
}
Template.lists.ownerOfList = function(id)
{
     return ( Meteor.userId() == Lists.findOne({_id : id}).owner);
}
Template.lists.settings = function()
{
     return {
          position: "top",
          limit: 5,
          rules: [
          {
               token: '',
               collection: Meteor.users,
               field: "username",
               template: Template.userPill
          }]
     }
}
Template.lists.events({
     'submit #list-add-form'  : function(e, t) {
          /* Checklisten ausgeben */
          e.preventDefault();
          var name = t.find('#list-name').value;
          var id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf();
          var id_block = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf();

         Lists.insert({_id : id, name : name, owner : Meteor.userId()});
         Meteor.users.update({_id : Meteor.userId()}, {$addToSet :{lists : id}});
         Listitems.insert({_id : id_block, name : "", items: []});
         Lists.update(id, {$addToSet : {items : id_block}});

     },
     'click .clickOnList' : function(e)
     {
        /* Eventhandler fuer klick auf Checkliste */
        Session.set("activeListId", e.target.id);
        $("#"+e.target.id).siblings('li').removeClass("active");
        $("#"+e.target.id).addClass("active");


     },
     'mouseover .clickOnList' : function (e,t) {
         $( ".deleteLists" ).each(function( index, item ) {
             if ( item.getAttribute("data-id") == e.target.getAttribute("data-id")) {
                 item.style.visibility = 'visible';
             } else {
                 item.style.visibility = 'hidden';
             }
         });
     },
     'mouseleave .clickOnList' : function (e,t) {
         $( ".deleteLists" ).each(function( index, item ) {
                  item.style.visibility = 'hidden';

         });
     },


     'click .deleteLists' : function(e, t)
     {
         /* Eventhandler zum loeschen einer Checkliste */
        var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
        Meteor.call("removeList", id);
        console.log("test");
     },
     'click .changeListnameButton' : function(e,t) {
         var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");

         document.getElementById("changerForm_" + id).style.visibility = 'visible';
         document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
         document.getElementById("changerText_" + id).focus();
     },
     'dblclick .clickOnList' : function(e,t){
         var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");

         document.getElementById("changerForm_" + id).style.visibility = 'visible';
         document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
         document.getElementById("changerText_" + id).focus();


       },
     'submit .changeList-name-form' : function(e,t) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
         var text = document.getElementById("changerText_" + id).value;
         if(text != '') {
             Meteor.call("changeListName", id, text);
         }

         if (Session.get("activeListId", e.target.id) == id ) {
             Session.set("activeListName", text);
         }


         document.getElementById("changerForm_" + id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
         document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';



     },
     'blur .list_name' : function(e,t) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
         var text = document.getElementById("changerText_" + id).value;
         if((text != '') && (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden')) {
             Meteor.call("changeListName", id, text);
         }

         if (Session.get("activeListId", e.target.id) == id ) {
             Session.set("activeListName", text);
         }

         document.getElementById("changerForm_" + id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
         document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';



     },
     'click .userForListModal' : function(e,t) {
          e.preventDefault();
          activeListName = e.target.id;
          activeListID = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
          //console.log(activeListID + " " + activeListName);
          //console.log("New user for Liste" + Lists.findOne({_id : activeListID}).name);
          userForList(activeListID);
          $("#userForListModalLabel").html("Benutzer der Liste '"+ activeListName+ "'");

     },
     'submit #list-addUser-form' : function(e,t) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var newUser = $('#name-list-addUser').val();
          Meteor.call("addUserToList", newUser, activeListID, function(error,result)
                  {
                    if (error) {
                         console.log(error.reason);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         if (result == 1) {
                              $('#userForListModalerrorMessage').fadeIn(1000, function() {$(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);});
                              $('#userForListModalerrorMessage').html("<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Benutzer wurde nicht gefunden...</div>");
                         }
                         else if (result == 2) {
                              $('#userForListModalerrorMessage').fadeIn(1000, function() {$(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);});
                              $('#userForListModalerrorMessage').html("<div class=\"alert alert-warning\">Benutzer ist Besitzer der Liste...</div>");
                         }
                    }
                  });
     }
 });

function userForList(id)
{
     try
     {
          var owner = Lists.findOne({_id : id}).owner;
          var members = Lists.findOne({_id : id}).member;          
     }
     catch(e){

     }
     output = "<ul>";
     output += "<li> Besitzer der Liste: <ul><li>" + owner + "</li></ul></li>";
     output += "<li>Mitarbeiter der Liste: <ul>"
     if (members != undefined) {
          for(i=0; i<members.length; i++)
          {
               output+= "<li>" + members[i] + "</li>";
          }
     }

     output += "</ul></li></ul>";
     $('#userForListModalUsers').html(output);
}
```

main.js (server):

```js
Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
Meteor.publish("lists", function(){

    var ListsOfUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id : this.userId}).lists;
    return Lists.find({_id :{ $in : ListsOfUser}});
});

Lists.allow({

    insert : function(userID, list)
    {
        return (userID && (list.owner === userID));
    },
    //todo
    update : function(userID)
    {
        return true;
    },

    //todo
    remove : function(userID)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an extra </div> in your template. Is that on typo on stackoverflow or is that indeed in your code? BTW, I don't think you need the "this." in the template.

Comment: How do you add new items, and where is the lists field in the user objects defined/set?

Comment: i shortened the source code because i thought it might be confusing. i will add the whole code!

Comment: Do you have to add your entire code in order to answer that question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is happening because the ListsOfUser variable in your Meteor.publish "lists" function is not a reactive data source.  ListsOfUser is an array drawn from your result set, not a reactive cursor.  Therefore it is not being invalidated server side when a user adds a new list on the client.  From the Meteor docs (note the last sentence especially):

```
If you call Meteor.subscribe within a reactive computation, for example using
Deps.autorun,the subscription will automatically be cancelled when the computation
is invalidated or stopped; it's not necessary to call stop on subscriptions made
from inside autorun. However, if the next iteration of your run function subscribes
to the same record set (same name and parameters), Meteor is smart enough to skip a
wasteful unsubscribe/resubscribe.
```

ListsOfUser is not changing when a user adds a new list, so you are not being unsubscribed and resubscribed to the lists publication.  (Note also that Meteor.users.findOne() is also not a reactive data source - you might want to switch it to Meteor.users.find() depending on how you go about making ListsOfUser reactive).

There are a few ways you could go about making the user lists reactive.

First, you could publish both the user cursor and the lists cursor, either separately or as an array in the same publish function, place both subscriptions in your Deps.autorun, and then fish out the user lists client side in a helper.

```
Meteor.publish("userWithLists", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(
      {_id: this.userId},
      {fields: {'lists': 1}}
    );
  });
```

Second, you could publish the static array of user lists as its own Collection and then use cursor.observe or cursor.observeChanges to track when it changes.  While my understanding is that this is closest to the "correct" or "Meteor" way of doing it, it is also apparently quite verbose and I have not tried it.  This tutorial goes into great detail about how you would tackle something like this: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/aGHZygsphtTWELpKZ

Third, you could simply stick the user lists into your Session object, which is already reactive, and then publish your Lists.find() based on the Session, i.e.:

```
Meteor.publish("lists", function(lists){/* find code goes here */});
```

and

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe("lists", Session.get("listsOfUser"));
});
```

This last one is probably an overuse / abuse of the Session object, particularly if your listsOfUser grows large, but should work as a hack.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer pointed out the difficulty!
Suggestion number one sounds very good. Can you give me an example code? It took me an hour to try this but didn't work out:

Server:

`myLists = new Meteor.Collection("mylists");
Meteor.publish("myLists", function(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id : this.userId}).lists;
});  //find with limit is not working`

and on client:

`myLists = new Meteor.Collection("myLists")
Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('lists');
    Meteor.subscribe("listitems");
    Meteor.subscribe("users");
    //Meteor.subscribe("myLists");
})`

Comment: I just edited my answer to clarify a sample publish under "First"  Keep in mind that you can't publish a .findOne() query if you want it to be reactive.  It needs to be a .find() query.  The current user is already published so the point is to get his .lists which are not automatically included.  Sorry for not making that clear initially.

Comment: Okay thanks again. Publishing the .lists of a user is working fine (.lists contains ids of the lists). Now I'm trying to publish all Lists of a collection that are in the user object. `Meteor.publish("lists", function(){   
    return Lists.find({_id :{ $in : myLists}});    
});`
This is not working (TypeError before starting) . Do I have to resend myLists from the client?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Internal exception while processing message { msg: 'sub', id: 'TMF6eXvznjxwnzwNJ', name: 'lists', params: [] } Converting circular structure to JSON TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

//edit: resending the myLists as argument to the publish function also fails

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but still someone might be seeking for the answer. And the answer is `Meteor.publishComposite` available with a publish-composite package - https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

And there's an example there

```
Meteor.publishComposite('topTenPosts', {
    find: function() {
        // Find top ten highest scoring posts
        return Posts.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 10 });
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(post) {
                // Find post author. Even though we only want to return
                // one record here, we use "find" instead of "findOne"
                // since this function should return a cursor.
                return Meteor.users.find(
                    { _id: post.authorId },
                    { limit: 1, fields: { profile: 1 } });
            }
        },
        {
            find: function(post) {
                // Find top two comments on post
                return Comments.find(
                    { postId: post._id },
                    { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 2 });
            },
            children: [
                {
                    find: function(comment, post) {
                        // Find user that authored comment.
                        return Meteor.users.find(
                            { _id: comment.authorId },
                            { limit: 1, fields: { profile: 1 } });
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I am rather new to meteor but, in your server code, should it not be:

var ListsOfUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id : Meteor.userId}).lists;

rather than:

var ListsOfUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id : Meteor.userId}).lists;

Comment: Using Meteor.userId instead of this.userId throws an error on serverside

Comment: These two statements are identical.